# Last comma in JSON Array to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am having a problem with the last comma when I am using PHP echoing JSON Array to android

Here is my code

```
If ($commentResult>0) 
echo "[";
    { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($commentResult)) {

    echo json_encode($row).",";
    }
echo "]";
```

Android can't read this, it printed out JSONException:Vale at 3 is null

Comment: If I don't put the comma on it, android still can't read the array

Comment: can you post example of JSONArray generated by your PHP code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? If you want to give an entire array then put json_encode over the entire array instead of trying to manually build it.

```
$comments=array();
if($commentResult>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($commentResult)){
        $comments[]=$row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($comments);
```

*Also, a side tip, don't use mysql_ functions. Instead use PDO or mysqli, which are better supported and get you rid of this whole while($row) business.*

Comment: This is probably, by far, the simplest solution. Original poster should mark this as the answer.

Comment: I should, indeed. Thank you kristovaher!

Answer (score 0):

The way you form you json is really strange. Don't know if it's an issue but you can try it in a more clean way:

```
if ($commentResult) {
    for ($data = array(); $row = mysql_fetch_array($commentResult); $data[] = $row);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will generate valid json?

Answer (score 0):

What ever JSON you are generating using PHP, Just verify that in http://jsonlint.com/. if output is wrong it wont validate other wise its OK from PHP side.